# PORT PROBE at a known malicious host in socket.io port

Tags: socket.io

Using socket.io and open one port for that.
From that on, I got many message from AWS GuardDuty.

So changed as adding "Deny Ip Filtering"

```
// FOR ALARM SERVICE
const webSocketServer = require('socket.io').Server
const webSocketServerInstance = new webSocketServer(portNumber, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["http://www.myhomepagename", "http://www.myhomepagename", `http://www.myhomepagename:${portNumber}`, `http://www.myhompagename:${portNumber}`],
    pingTimeout: 5000
  },
  allowRequest: (req, callback) => {
    const incomeIp = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.socket.remoteAddress
    console.log("NEW CONNECTED IP", incomeIp) //Printed as "NEW CONNECTED IP ::ffff:v.x.y.z". So use 'includes' function for matching.
    const isOriginValid = ENV_GLOBAL['DenyIPs']['List'].filter(ip => incomeIp.includes(ip)).length === 0
    if(!isOriginValid)
      console.log("PORT PROBE DETECT.", incomeIp)
    callback(null, isOriginValid)
  } 
})
```

So the time term of alarm from GuardDuty has been low aganst no blocking IPs. But it continues about every day term.

Is any solution about secure coding?